# How to implement document saving in OS X

Tags: macos

I am new to OS X programming. I have a document based application. But I don't know how to implement the save feature. All I know is to use `- (IBAction)saveDocument:(id)sender`. But what do I do next?

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what format and where you will store your document's contents. You can write them out to disc as a file or store them in a local database or in the cloud with CloudKit.

Most likely you will want a local file. Look up NSFileManager and write some code!